# Vulkan and transparent windows

Tags: vulkan

I'm currently adapting my personal engine to Vulkan and I want to reimplement transparent windows, which I already had with OpenGL.

I thought that all I need to do is to select the correct color format ( with alpha channel ) and to set the `compositeAlpha` property of `VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR`to `VK_COMPOSITE_ALPHA_POST_MULTIPLIED_BIT_KHR`.

However clearing the window with a full transparent color doesn't provide the expected results. It's fully opaque.

Of course my window system, which didn't change since I had OpenGL, supports it and when I just disable the rendering I also can't click through at the supposed position of the window, this tells me that it's there.

Are there any other required changes to make this work?

#### Some infos

The image format is `VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM` and I oriented the vulkan setup as found in [Sascha Willems examples](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/).

Comment: What are the supported modes returned by `vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR`?

Comment: @krOoze And you are right, isn't supported, i wonder if this is driver limited.

Comment: I guess I will answerize it, so the case can be closed...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That capability (as most others) have to be queried before usage about whether it is supported. Otherwise it is invalid to use it.

This particular feature is queried by `vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR` as `pSurfaceCapabilities->supportedCompositeAlpha`. It is a bitfield/flag-set, so more than one mode or none can be supported.

I think the result/feature support may be influenced by the VkSurface. That is, how the platform window was created. Or maybe the driver maker simply did not implement it yet (despite that feature being supportable).

Since it worked for you before in OGL, the later is more likely. But couldn't hurt to play with the platform window creation parameters...

Comment: BTW, that case should have been caught by validation layers. Make sure to enable them and benefit...

Comment: Well validation layers are fine, but i'm not so sure how to enable them with C#. Was already enough work to get C# run on vulkan without using too much unmanaged code. :-)

Comment: Same way as in C++? You enable the `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation` layer and properly initialize the `VK_EXT_debug_report` extension stuff when making Instance. Can be worth it to get it working - e.g. AIS could have helped you with this particular Q.

Answer (score 3):

Dunno if this is still relevant, but I got it working with transparent windows through GLFW. *(If you are not using GLFW you may dismiss this answer!)*

As stated [here](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/window_guide.html#window_transparency), there are two ways of obtaining window transparency: framebuffer transparency (alpha bit), and window transparency.

For window transparency it is sufficient to call `glfwSetWindowOpacicity(GLFWwindow*, float)`, where the opacity value should be in the range (0, 1].

**NOTE:** Since GLFW does not support using both transparency methods at the same time, we must still use `VK_COMPOSITE_ALPHA_OPAQUE_BIT_KHR` in the `compositeAlpha` field of the `VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR` object.
Window transparency may not be supported on all systems, which is why GLFW provides us with a function `glfwGetWindowOpacity(GLFWwindow*)`, to check if calling the first methods was successful.

Comment: While i do not use i appreciate posting a answer to such a old question!

Comment: Yeah I thought - maybe someone will appreciate this at some point. I was search for an answer to this as late as earlier this week. :)