# Transparent window possible with integrated graphics only

Tags: windows, windows-10, driver, transparency, vulkan

I have been following the vulkan tutorial for a while now and just got to the part where I was able to create a triangle.
I wanted to get transparency working because it's a major part of my project.

I made the clear color alpha value 0.0, and started experimenting.
I spent some time bashing my head against the wall, because the validation layers kept telling me that these alpha compositing(?) flags were not supported, so I went as far as to create the windows myself (instead of with glfw, which is what I was doing).

Some time later, I noticed that the support for the flags is there, but only for my integrated graphics card:
[image: flags]

So when using the 1050 I get the black:
[image]
But when using integrated graphics:
[image: integrated run]
boom works

This was even a bit weird to me because it was working even though I was still setting the compositeAlpha to `VK_COMPOSITE_ALPHA_OPAQUE_BIT_KHR`. Looks like windows does the alpha blending without the need for the flags.
I did then experiment with changing it to the `POST` and `PRE` flags, but saw no difference at all.

I'm new to this so I'm at a loss as to how things may work.
One more thing is, my windows advanced display settings shows this:
[image: windows setting shows integrated card in use for display]

And so I thought that maybe, as it's the integrated graphics that's doing the rendering of what seems to be the windows system (I'm assuming that's what "display 1" entails), it is the only adapter that has access to those framebuffers and is thus the only that's capable of doing the blending.

Am I right? Because if I am, then I must find a way to display with the driver that's doing the windows rendering, and render with the most powerful one, since it seems that windows often picks integrated graphics for it's display stuff.

And if I'm not, I'd be really glad for you to explain to me why I'm dumb :D

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vulkan and transparent windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38281796/vulkan-and-transparent-windows)

Comment: Per the https://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/ AMD and NVIDIA do not currently report the transparency flag. Technically the cap query is dependent on `VkSurface`. I would try asking AMD or NVIDIA directly via their dev forums otherwise we will just might have to resort to trial and error (although e.g. `WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP` style flag sound appropriate here).  It should be possible to achieve the transparency outside Vulkan if desperate or for compatibility.

Comment: Per your descriptions I would say the Intel driver is non-conformant.

Comment: I think it should not matter from functional standpoint where your display is connected, and windows just "glues" all GPUs to all ports (perhaps to annoyance of some) similar to whatsitcalled on Linuxes (Xinerama?).

Comment: @krOoze The other thread didn't actually have any answer as to how to actually acheive transparency.
Also I'm not familiar with this `WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP` and the https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/extended-window-styles description isn't too helpful. You say it should be possible to acheive transparency outside of vulkan, I think I have managed to, sort of. The window starts off as transparent, but once vulkan is rendering with the 1050 it goes black.
That doesn't happen with integrated graphics, it just works.
If display shouldn't matter, what is going on?

Comment: No, but having satisfying answer is not the same as not being a duplicate. Think about it this way. Potential answer to your question will be relevant to the other person's Q. Read how duplicates work on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) (some duplicates are encouraged on SO, and being flaged as one is **not** a punishment).

Comment: Sorry, lot of speculation from me. It might be efficient to directly ask NV and\or AMD if they do not support it at all, or if it just needs a window created with some special flags.  Not sure if anyone answers here. If you say `OPAQUE`, it is not a surprise it goes black. AIS I think Intel should not behave that way if you tell it to create `OPAQUE` swapchain. By "outside Vulkan" I meant drawing to off-screen buffer (and **not** using Vulkan Swapchain at all), then deliver that data to the Window in OS-specific way (i.e. win32 API). That is problamatic, but it is a path forward.

Comment: @krOoze So I didn't notice a couple things. Intel graphics only has opaque and inherit. Inherit would make sense since it just leaves it to the OS, but its weird since it also works with opaque. I was also able to achieve transparency with directx a while ago on my desktop, which has a 980ti only. Upon testing that same directx program on my laptop, and restricting it to the 1050 in the Nvidia control panel, I find that transparency also works here. Does that help you zero in on any speculations you had?

Comment: I'm guessing the opaque thing is just Intel misbehaving as you said. But if the Intel one can do it in vulkan, that means vulkan is capable of doing it on windows, and if directx can do it with these other cards, shouldn't that mean that it's also supposedly possible with vulkan?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195847/discussion-between-trist-and-krooze).